# Upload photo in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel file upload gives the user error when trying to upload images

`Get error: local.ERROR: Driver [] is not supported.`

How to fix its problem?

```
public function channelAvatar(Request $request, Channel $channel)
{
    // validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        'photo' => ['required', 'image', Rule::dimensions()->minWidth(250)->minHeight(250)->ratio(1 / 1)],
    ]);

    // fill variables
    $filename = time() . str_random(16) . '.png';
    $image = Image::make($request->file('photo')->getRealPath());
    $folder = 'channels/avatars';

    // crop it
    $image = $image->resize(250, 250);

    // optimize it
    $image->encode('png', 60);

    // upload it
    Storage::put($folder.'/'.$filename, $image->__toString());
    $imageAddress = $this->webAddress() . $folder . '/' . $filename;

    // delete the old avatar
    Storage::delete('channels/avatars/' . str_after($channel->avatar, 'channels/avatars/'));

    // update channel's avatar
    $channel->update([
        'avatar' => $imageAddress,
    ]);
    $this->putChannelInTheCache($channel);

    return $imageAddress;
}
```

Uploading locally or to `FTP` still gives the same error.

Comment: *Which* line in this code generates this error?

Comment: What does the `config/filesystem.php` contain?

Comment: **filesystem.php**
'ftp' => [
                  'driver'   => 'ftp',
                  'host'     => env('FTP_HOST', 'uashared14.twinservers.net'),
                  'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME', 'aintoday'),
                  'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD', '*******'),

              ],
I think problem here: Storage::put($folder.'/'.$filename, $image->__toString());
        $imageAddress = $this->webAddress() . $folder . '/' . $filename;

Comment: Whats in your `.env` for `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER`?

Comment: **.env**

FTP_HOST=uashared14.twinservers.net
FTP_PORT=21
FTP_USERNAME=aintoday
FTP_PASSWORD=******
FTP_ROOT=/public_ftp

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a Storage option without a specific disk, Laravel uses  the default driver. It seems like you have specified `local` as default driver but you do not have it configured.

As per your `config/filesystem.php` you have :

```
'ftp' => [ 
    'driver' => 'ftp', 
    'host' => env('FTP_HOST', 'test.something.net'), 
    'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME', 'someusername'), 
    'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD', '*******'), 
],
```

So you need to specify this as a default driver. You can do that by adding :

`FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=ftp` inside the `.env` file.

And then inside the 'config/filesystem.php` add following :

`'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),`

Now whenever you do `Storage::something()` it will use default driver. (Something you will have `local` as the default one`

You can also specify it if you would like :

`Storage::disk('ftp')->something()` But if your all storage operations use one disk  then better specify as default.

Comment: A heads up to do `php artisan config:clear` to let the env changes take effect